# yarn build showing error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: angular, angular6

node -v
v8.9.4
npm -v
5.6.0

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'",
    "lint:fix": "yarn run lint -- --fix",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "cleanup": "rimraf build/{aot,www}",
    "clean-www": "rimraf build//www/app/{src,build/}",
    "start": "yarn run webpack:dev",
    "serve": "yarn run start",
    "build": "yarn run webpack:prod",
    "test": "yarn run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "yarn test -- --watch",
    "webpack:dev": "yarn run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9061 --watch-content-base",
    "webpack:build:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:main",
    "webpack:prod:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile",
    "webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www",
    "webpack:test": "yarn run test",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=2096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=2096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
    "postinstall": "node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js"
  }
```

yarn build showing error like-

```
yarn run v1.22.4

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```